# Facebook SDK 3.0 HelloFacebookSample build errors

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having trouble compiling the HelloFacebookSample app that comes with Facebook SDK 3.0.

Firstly, I should say I'm using Xcode 4.0.2, iOS SDK 4.3 and OS X 10.6.8. (I'm struggling to find a way to download Xcode 4.2 without upgrading to Lion or Mountain Lion, which I'm reluctant to do.)

When I try to build the sample project, I get the following build errors:

1) Unexpected '@' in program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {    // error on this line
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HFAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

2) Expected identifier

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];    // error on this line
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // FBSample logic
    // if the app is going away, we close the session object
    [FBSession.activeSession close];                       // error on this line
}
```

I can "resolve" these problems (not sure if I resolved them correctly), but then I then get the following linking error:

> Framework not found Accounts
>
> **Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1**

Can anyone help me at all? I won't have much luck integrating Facebook into my app if I can't even build the sample projects!

Comment: Cn you build any project? Go to File -> New Project. Does it build?

Comment: Hi, yeah I can build all my other projects, everything I built before downloading the Facebook SDK. I did extensive research and resolved the first two build errors, it's just the linking error that is still a problem. But the Facebook SDK 3.0 says it is compatible with iOS 4.0 and later, so I thought the sample tests would build with no problems at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved all the issues. It appears the sample is not immediately compatible with iOS 4.3 or Xcode 4.0.2. Here's what I did:

1) Unexpected @ in program; changed to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HFAppDelegate class]));
}
```

2) Expected identifier; replaced

```
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];    // error on this line
...
    [FBSession.activeSession close];                       // error on this line
```

with

```
    return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];
...
    [[FBSession activeSession] close];
```

3) Framework not found Accounts; turns out it's not required, so I just deleted the framework from the Frameworks group in the Project Navigator.

4) I forgot to say in my original post: keyword `strong` was unknown, so I macro'd it as `retain` at the top of the file **FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h** as follows:

```
#define strong retain
```

And now the HelloFacebookSample app compiles with no errors or warnings and it works fine. All interactions with Facebook work.

Hope this helps someone else in the future! If it helps you, please vote it up!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I'll do my best.

The first error is because your'e using `@autoreleasepool`. I think this is quite new syntax for the auto release pool.
Before it was something like this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *string;
string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]; // NSString or any other allocated objects
                                                // With autorelease tag
/* use the string */
[pool drain];
```

You should look at projects for X-code 4.0.2 and your iOS SDK to find how the main function is there.

I'm looking at the other error, I believe it has something to do with the iOS SDK you're using. Isn't it possible to update only the SDK? without updating xcode?

if I'll find something, I'll let you know

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I actually already resolved the build errors - I'm just confused why I had to make any changes to the sample code, because the Facebook SDK 3.0 says it is compatible with iOS 4.0 and later, and I'm on 4.3! So it's just the linking error, and this is because Accounts.framework is not found. Does anyone know where I can find that? I looked it up and it seems like it comes with iOS 5.0, so why does Facebook SDK 3.0 say it's compatible with iOS 4.0 and later?