# Segmentation fault: 11 Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-iphone, segmentation-fault

I'm struggling to add Facebook functionality to my Cocos2d iOS game using the Facebook iOS sdk v3.1. I've been trying to follow the "how-to's" on Facebooks Developer site but I'm running into the following errors.

- error: expected ':' before '.' token
- internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11

The errors are occurring every time a method tries to access the "FBSession.activeSession". The code was copied and pasted directly from Facebook's tutorial.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    // (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];//Error occurs here!
}
```

Has anyone experienced this error? Additionally, does anyone know of any updated tutorials illustrating Facebook integration using Cocos2d? Everything I'm turning up is very outdated.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Just updaded to Xcode 4.5.2. Getting the same errors!

Comment: And you're sure there are no unclosed braces or incomplete syntax anywhere else in the file? (Sorry, I have to ask ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Check your compiler in Build Settings- I received this same error when building under LLVM GCC 4.2 but switching back to Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 addressed the issue.

[image: Compiler setting in Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution here: [Facebook SDK 3.0 HelloFacebookSample build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359436/facebook-sdk-3-0-hellofacebooksample-build-errors)
replace `FBSession.activeSession`by `[FBSession activeSession]`